# Using RavenDB for a solution with a complex user object permission model

Tags: .net, database-design, architecture, ravendb, nosql

We have an application, currently built on a SQL Server database with a "fairly" complicated data permission model.

At the center of our Application is an entity called `Record`. Whether a user can see a record is based on the user themselves, the workgroup they're part of and the organisation they are part of.

In the diagram below, a logged in `User` gets to see records to which they're directly assigned, or they're part of a workgroup to which the record is assigned, or they're workgroup is part of an organisation to which the record is assigned.

[image]

This is a bit of a pain in "SQL + NHibernate" land as there are some messy joins and unions being used to get the results I need. This is just one example of data which is permissioned this way in the application.

I'm just wondering how suitable this type of model is to a NoSQL/RavenDB object hierarchy and if there are any performance considerations / object model re-architecting that might be required.

Comment: Where do you expect most of the update-based activity to occur? E. Also, try and draw aggregate boundaries around items that should be kept consistent as a whole - so does a `Workgroup` internal affect an organisation? Does a `User.Address` affect the `UserRecord`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Note this answer is incomplete, as I am trying to discover more about the question

I've wrote some code to try and work out the 1-to-many relationships from what is presented.

Is this how it is structured *at the moment*?

```
public class Organisation
{
   public List<Workgroup> Workgroups { get; set; }
   public List<OrganisationRecord> Records { get; set; }
}

public class Workgroup 
{
   public List<User> Users { get; set; }
   public List<WorkgroupRecord> Records { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
   public List<UserRecord> Records { get; set; }
}
```

From what I am understanding - a record comes in 3 forms:

- OrganisationRecord
- WorkgroupRecord
- UserRecord

And these would look something like, like a [Table Per Hierarchy](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph):

```
public abstract class Record { }
public class OrganisationRecord : Record {}
public class WorkgroupRecord : Record {}
public class UserRecord : Record {}
```